# People's memories edited for funeral display

Tags: identify-this-movie

Looking for a movie probably from the **90's**, maybe **00's**; almost certainly **American**, where the protagonist (?) has a job of compiling something like **"best-of reels" of dead people's memories** as part of a funeral service.

I remember a beautiful computer interface within a wood (-panel) desk with an inset keyboard, and I think something like track-balls/jog wheels.

The story is about some discovery the protagonist makes in one of his clients' videos. It seems that everybody has a recording device à la "[The entire history of you](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2089050/combined)" or "[Strange days](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114558/combined)", and this is used to compile a home-movie style video to remember the deceased by.

The protagonist is probably a **white male in his 40s**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The Final Cut (2004)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0364343/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl)

> The story is set in a world where implanted microchips can record all
>   moments of an individual's life. The chips are removed upon death so
>   the images can be edited into something of a highlight reel for loved
>   ones who want to remember the deceased. Caviezel portrays the leader
>   of the organization that opposes this technology's development.

Comment: It is!
Thank you!

I guess I remembered the brass part wrong; will edit